# Views getting mixing up on EditText focus in Fragment inside ViewPager

Tags: android, view, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm facing a View mixing up issue when I put `Fragment` which contains a `EditText` in a `ViewPager`.

You can see my actual layout design in image_1 .

Case 1: I put the `Fragment` inside a `ViewPager` and clicked on first `EditText` in the layout to enter something. But the result was image_2. All the `View` got mixed because there in no enough space for containing all `View`. But with respect to android's actual behavior all the `Views` inside the layout should move up and focus the current selected `EditText`.

Case 2: I put `Fragment` directly to `Activity` without `ViewPager`. I tried the same thing.(image_3). I got desired android behavior here.

**1) Why is it so?
2) How can I solve this issue?**
image_1
[image: actual layout]

image_2
[image: layout behavior inside view pager]

image_3
[image: layout outside viewpager]

My layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/container_dropshadow" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/content_margin"
        android:background="@color/dark_background" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="send"
            android:text="@string/send" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/descriptionEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/sendButton"
            android:hint="@string/description"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
            android:maxLength="500" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/departmentEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/descriptionEditText"
            android:hint="Department"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/subjectEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/departmentEditText"
            android:hint="Subject"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:singleLine="true" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/selectAFileLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/subjectEditText"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_browse"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fileTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Select a file"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/browseFileButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="getFile"
                android:text="..." />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/selectAFileLinearLayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/upload_file_title_margin_bottom"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/upload_files_message"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/heading_font_size" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following in manifest for your activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```